# Google USB Package isn't showing in SDK Mananger

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I recently downloaded and installed Eclipse Java EE IDE: Indigo Service Release 2. I made a simple application that runs well on the emulator; now I want to try and run it on my android mobile device. From the Android Developers site, I followed the instructions to do so until I got to the point where I needed to locate the USB driver folder for the Google USB driver found in sdk\extras\google\usb_driver. I do not have that driver, so I went on to download it. I was told it was found in the SDK manager under "Extras". I proceeded in Eclipse to Window > Android SDK Manger. I waited for it get done fetching and then went to "Extras". Making sure "Updates/New" was checked as well as "Installed"; however, the only thing under the "Extras" tab is "Android Support Package" and nothing else.

And so here I am ... stuck on what I need to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of the SDK tools are you using?

Comment: Did you run the Android SDK Manager as Administrator?

Comment: The problem was that I wasn't running revision 17 of SDK tools and also I wasn't running SDK tools as admin! I finally got it to show up and I should have it now! Thanks!

Comment: StayPuff... exactly how did you get this running!?  I don't have a google folder either.  What do you mean running SDK Tools as admin?  I don't see anything named SDK Tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html

You can get the USB drivers for most devices from the manufacturer's site listed here.

As far as the Google USB drivers, I would ensure you are running the latest version of the Android SDK tools and to try running the program as admin.

Comment: Incase it helps anyone else - I had revision 15 of the Andriod SDK Manager and couldn't see Google USB Driver. Downloaded latest version from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html (revision 18 in my case) and I CAN now see the driver to install.

Comment: What a horror show on Win 7.  After many reboots and driver install attempts, for the Nexus 4, I downloaded the Google SDK.  Then ran the SDK manager to install the drivers.  From there all went down nicely once the key was confirmed on the Nexus 4.

Comment: It gives 404 now

Answer (score 4):

I just noticed that bringing up the SDK manager from within Eclipse will not show the Google USB driver... However, opening it up via the Start Menu will. (Also, run it as Administrator).

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue and I traced my root cause to this error. I forgot to install Google USB driver. This can be done via SDK manager, ie Android studio->File->Settings->Appearance and behavior->System Settings->Android SDK in tab "SDK tools" check the option for "Google USB Driver" and Apply.

Comment: That's the missing solution

Comment: I can confirm that this was the method I used to download the Google USB Driver and it worked. Until I did this, when I plugged my phone in to attempt remote debugging, I was never prompted to confirm the connection signature, even after revoking any existing USB debugging authorizations.  After downloading the driver in Android Studio's SDK manager and updating the ADB interface's driver in Device Manager on Windows 8.1, I was prompted to accept the connection signature when plugging in my phone to use Chrome's remote debugging tool.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue and I traced my root cause to this error message in the log. 
[XML verification failed for http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository.addon.xml](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30659)

If this is the case, make sure your JDK/JRE version is 1.6 or greater.

If you are using Windows 7 64 bit, make sure you update your x86 JDK/JRE version as well.