# SDK manager does not list Google USB driver - Unable to install it

Tags: android, sdk

I am very new to android development.

I have seen questions similar to this, but mine did not get resolved even after doing all what has been said. So, decided to post a new question for myself.

I am trying to run my android application from my Nexus 7 tablet. I use Windows 7 64 bit version. I downloaded the latest available revision of SDK and used it. However, the SDK manager does not list any new items. Only the items installed already are listed in it.

When I try to reload the list, it fails to fetch from the repository.

At this point, I did a lot of search online, and did the following..

1. I have enabled the "Force https:// to be fetched using http..
2. Disabled firewalls. (I use mc-afee).
3. Cleared cache in SDK manager.

But, none of this worked.

I also read somewhere that proxy should be configured to get this done. But, I am not sure where to get my proxy settings from(to be put into SDK manager). I checked it in the LAN settings of internet explorer. But, there is no proxy set there. I just use "Automatically detect settings".

Can someone please help me out here?I need to install the USB driver and run my app on my tablet.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention. I am running SDK manager as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following answer to see if it gets you anywhere:

[Google USB Package isn't showing in SDK Mananger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910038/google-usb-package-isnt-showing-in-sdk-mananger?rq=1)

It seems that they have experienced an issue similar to yours.

Comment: The originator of the post also mentioned: _"The problem was that I wasn't running revision 17 of SDK tools and also I wasn't running SDK tools as admin! I finally got it to show up and I should have it now!"_

Did you try running it as admin as well?

Also, which version of the SDK are you running? Some people experience problems when running an old version. You can find the newest version of the SDK [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Anoter issue might be that JDK/JRE is outdated:
_"If you are using Windows 7 64 bit, make sure you update your x86 JDK/JRE version as well."_

Comment: I tried running as admin. I use JDK 1.7.

The SDK is also the latest. I downloaded it from the same link that you mentioned.

Comment: You just put a unuseful link