# SDK manager Android studio 3.5.3

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

hello I just install Android studio 3.5.3 for Mac and I want to install google repository and Google USB but I can not find them in SDK Manager

[image]

thank you

Comment: USB driver is required only for Windows. "If you're developing on Mac OS X or Linux, then you do not need to install a USB driver." https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9910220/7765316) for Google USB drivers. (Only windows needs drivers)

google repository is added via Gradle file (Newer libraries from Google Repositories are available as gradle dependencies by adding google() on your gradle file)